# Can we create custom backend in terraform?

Tags: mongodb, terraform, devops

I want to store my `terraform.tfstate` file in mongodb database. I could see that there is no default option available for mongodb as a backend in terraform. So, can we create a custom backend in terraform (In my case, I want to create mongodb backend to store and fetch `terraform.tfstate` file. If not possible, any work around to complete this aim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, like you said there is no `mongodb` as default backend. But there are several existing backends that would help.

But, if are still looking at solutions only using `mongodb` as your default backend, you can still achieve it.

Along with `S3`, `postgres`, `azurerm`, `gcs` Terraform also supports backend using a REST client [http](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/http.html).

All you have to do is build a small HTTP server and expose an endpoint as shown below in your backend.

```
terraform {
  backend "http" {
    address = "http://tfstate.mycompany.io/store"
  }
}
```

And your server will be communicating with the Mongodb to store and retrieve data. But you need to have endpoints to POST, GET, DELETE, LOCK and UNLOCK configured in order to let Terraform to do the job. refer above documentation on status codes to return as well.

Comment: Yeah. Good catch. Let me try out this approach.